# OpenCV / VideoCapture / adding cameras, debugging parameters to existing cameras

Tags: windows, opencv, ubuntu, camera, drivers

I want to set exposure / gain parameters for various cameras (IEEE 1394, Logitech Webcam) using the **OpenCV / VideoCapture** class.  Most posts on this topic indicate that this is *trial-and-error*.

Isn't there a way to go about this more methodically?

A search for videocapture.cpp does not reveal the code in opencv-3.0-beta.  There is no header file specifically for the videocapture class; it must be buried in other header files.

How do I learn more about how videocapture (Ubuntu and/or Windows) works?  How it communicates with the drivers in the O/S?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source for `cvCreateCameraCapture()` in modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp to see why it is difficult to predict capabilities.  There are more than a few camera APIs that can be used depending on your system:

```
// try every possibly installed camera API
    for (int i = 0; domains[i] >= 0; i++)
    {
#if defined(HAVE_MSMF)         || \
    defined(HAVE_TYZX)         || \
    defined(HAVE_VFW)          || \
    defined(HAVE_LIBV4L)       || \
    defined(HAVE_CAMV4L)       || \
    defined(HAVE_CAMV4L2)      || \
    defined(HAVE_VIDEOIO)      || \
    defined(HAVE_GSTREAMER)    || \
    defined(HAVE_DC1394_2)     || \
    defined(HAVE_DC1394)       || \
    defined(HAVE_CMU1394)      || \
    defined(HAVE_MIL)          || \
    defined(HAVE_QUICKTIME)    || \
    defined(HAVE_QTKIT)        || \
    defined(HAVE_UNICAP)       || \
    defined(HAVE_PVAPI)        || \
    defined(HAVE_OPENNI)       || \
    defined(HAVE_OPENNI2)      || \
    defined(HAVE_XIMEA)        || \
    defined(HAVE_AVFOUNDATION) || \
    defined(HAVE_ANDROID_NATIVE_CAMERA) || \
    defined(HAVE_GIGE_API) || \
    defined(HAVE_INTELPERC)    || \
```

In Windows, it will probalby use VFW (`cvCreateCameraCapture_VFW`) to open a web cam, leading to `class CvCaptureCAM_VFW` if you want to debug it's use of VFW's `capCaptureSetSetup()` function that is used to set parameters.  In Linux, you might have to try using CMake on your system to see what APIs you can link with, but GStreamer and XIMEA among others are supported are supported

Comment: Ok... took a look.  I get how it seeks out other drivers in general.  However, it needs to point to something like `CvCaptureCAM_VFW` (for example).  Where is this code?  Seems to generic to be in a **DLL** or **so**.  Some advise to grab your video / stills with code written directly for the camera driver rather than contribute to **OpenCV**.  Thoughts?